# Limits of two fixed points of $E_\mu(x) = \mu e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Please let me know if this proof is OK.

**Problem statement:** Given that $E_\mu(x) = \mu e^x$, where $0 < \mu < 1/e$, show that if $q_\mu < p_\mu$ are fixed points, where $q_\mu$ is attractive and $p_\mu$ is repelling, then $\lim\limits_{\mu\to 0^+} q_\mu = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{\mu\to 0^+} p_\mu=\infty$.

**My attempt:**

Since we know that $p_\mu > q_\mu$ is repelling and $q_\mu$ is attractive, we know that $E'(p_\mu) > 1$ and $E'(q_\mu) < 1$. For this range of values of $\mu$, we can express: $E_\mu(x) = e^{x-\varepsilon}$, for any $\varepsilon > 1$. Now, $E'(\overline{x}) = E(\overline{x})$, and $E(q_\mu) = E'(q_\mu) = e^{q_\mu}e^{-\varepsilon} = q_\mu$. As $\mu \to 0^{+}$, $\varepsilon \to \infty$. Thus we have $\lim\limits_{\mu\to 0^+} q_\mu = e^{q_\mu} e^{-\varepsilon} < 1$, which implies that $q_\mu \to 0.\\
\\$
Similarly, $\lim\limits_{\mu\to 0^+} p_\mu = e^{p_\mu} e^{-\varepsilon} > 1$ implies that $p_\mu$ must approach $\infty$ faster than $\varepsilon$.

I'm a bit concerned about the final part, where I make conclusions about the limits.

Comment: It seems you are more or less circling around the somewhat simpler arguments that follow. Both points $q_\mu$ and $p_\mu$ solve $xe^{-x}=\mu$. Since $x\mapsto xe^{-x}$ is increasing on $x<1$ and decreasing on $x>1$, one knows that, for every $\mu<1/e$, $$0<q_\mu<1<p_\mu.$$ Now, $q_\mu=\mu e^{q_\mu}$ and $q_\mu<1$ hence, for every $\mu<1/e$, $$q_\mu<\mu e.$$ In particular, $q_\mu\to0$ when $\mu\to0$. On the other hand, $p_\mu=\log p_\mu-\log\mu$ and $p_\mu>1$ hence, for every $\mu<1/e$, $$p_\mu>-\log\mu.$$ In particular, $p_\mu\to\infty$ when $\mu\to0$.

Comment: It appears that $x\to xe^{-x}$ is decreasing for all $x\in (0, \infty)$.

Comment: It appears that you may want to draw a graph of the function before making such startling statements (or to explain how some function which is 0 at 0 and has limit 0 at oo can be decreasing on (0,oo)...)

Comment: Oops, my bad, I should've drawn the function indeed, instead of trying to "perceive" it analytically.

Comment: @Did: How do the facts that $\mu < 1/e$ and that $xe^{-x}$ is increasing on $x<1$ imply that $0 < q_\mu < 1 < p_\mu$?

Comment: Simply because $q$ and $p$ are the abscissas of the intersection of a horizontal line with the graph hence the variations of the function impose that $q<1<p$. (Note that all this is already explained in my first comment and that I might not want to repeat myself ad infinitum.)

Comment: Thank you. But I still find my proof considerably simpler. I understand this might be subjective.

Comment: As witnessed by the fact that you were not even aware that $0<q<1<p$, I guess.

Comment: @Did: one has first to prove that $q<1$ and $p>1$, but this is just one way to prove this theorem.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. For your information, I fail to understand the "proof" in your question.

Comment: Which part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: First problem: "for any $\epsilon>1$" Do you mean "for some $\epsilon>1$"? Then: What is $\bar x$? Then, why $\lim\mu e^q<1$? Then...

Comment: I mean "for any $\varepsilon > 1$" because $0 < \mu < 1/e$, so we can take any $\varepsilon>1$ to have $1/e^\varepsilon < 1/e$.
$\overline{x}$ is a fixed point.
$\mu e^q < 1$ because $E_\mu(x) = E_\mu'(x)$ for all $x$, and $E_\mu'(q_\mu) < 1$ because $q_\mu$ is attractive.

Comment: No you cannot take *any* $\varepsilon>1$, actually you have to use $\varepsilon=-\log\mu$.

Comment: Why not? If $\varepsilon > 1$ then $\mu = 1/e^{\varepsilon} < 1/e$.

Comment: Yeah, but for each $\mu$, one has to pick the correct $\epsilon$, not **any** $\epsilon$.

Comment: Right, but we don't know the value of $\mu$, we just consider all values between $0$ and $1/e$. We don't need to know concrete values of $\mu$ in this case. So $\varepsilon$ is just some value $>1$ for some value of $\mu$ in the range of $\mu's$.